# Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty

Tags: java, swing

anyone can help me? I got this exception in Netbeans

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: 
empty 
String
at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1842)
at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:538)
```

and this is part of my code that probably makes the exception :

```
   private void pizzaMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                        
   double cMeal = Double.parseDouble(costmeal.getText());
   double qPizza = Double.parseDouble(qtypizza.getText());
   double cPizaa = 6000;


        if(pizza.isSelected())
        {
        i[0] = (qPizza * cPizaa) + cMeal;
        String pMeal = String.format("%.2f", i[0]);
        costmeal.setText(pMeal); 
        }
}
```

Can anyone tell me how to fix it? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You have to check that costmeal.getText() and qtypizza.getText() both contain a valid number ,it seems that one of them is Empty based on the snap code and the stack trace.

Comment: Thanks it work, but costmeal is showing 6000.00 instead 6000, how to fix that? And also if I change the quantity it wont auto calculate

Comment: I follow the tutorial in youtube : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QTiAEHzirOk , and the code from tutorial are not running well

Answer (score 0):

NumberFormatException is an Exception that might be thrown when you try to convert a String into a number(int, double, float etc..). You have to handle the exception either by putting the code inside try catch or add the exception to the method signature.

```
private void pizzaMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) throws NumberFormatException {                                        
   double cMeal = Double.parseDouble(costmeal.getText());
   double qPizza = Double.parseDouble(qtypizza.getText());
   double cPizaa = 6000;
   if(pizza.isSelected())
   {
       i[0] = (qPizza * cPizaa) + cMeal;
       String pMeal = String.format("%.2f", i[0]);
       costmeal.setText(pMeal); 
    }
}
```

Or

```
private void  pizzaMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {       
    try{                                 
        double cMeal = Double.parseDouble(costmeal.getText());
        double qPizza = Double.parseDouble(qtypizza.getText());
        double cPizaa = 6000;


        if(pizza.isSelected())
        {
            i[0] = (qPizza * cPizaa) + cMeal;
            String pMeal = String.format("%.2f", i[0]);
           costmeal.setText(pMeal); 
    }
    }
    catch(NumberFormatException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it only catch and throw the exception, and show nothing in my jTextfield costmeal

Comment: Basically, if the text in 'costmeal' and 'qtypizza' is not a valid number, the exception is thrown. Make sure that they contain valid numbers.